# How to add an image to Visual Flow?

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

I cannot seem to find a way to add an image to my output screen, can this be done in Visual Flow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flow doesn't provide the standard way to add image, but there is a workaround to add image into Visual workflow.

Add a Display Text to screen page and enter HTML markup to that text like regular HTML. Visual workflow render all text as html text.

Ex:

[image]

In above image html tag is added to Display text `<img src="http://www.wolfgangdigital.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Google.jpg" width="100%"  height="auto" />` direct and saved it.
Output as:

[image]

This way you can do several customizations to visual workflow.

Comment: Beautifully explained

Comment: Does this still work? I get blank space where the image is supposed to go.

Comment: This option no longer works. Tested with Winter 17' Release.

Comment: This is working for Some jpg (not for all png s) images  for the below image it is not working .. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b4/Falck_logo.jpg ? am I missing something!